# Why doesn't node.js load the module I require?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I have node.js install on linux, and `file.js`. In the same directory I have `node_modules` directory with `lru-cache` module.

`file.js` does the following:

```
var lrucache = require('lru-cache')
```

But when I run it, it raises the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lru-cache'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/file.js:58:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

What is the problem? the same is working in other linux system.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your directory structure? There's probably sth wrong here. Btw I guess it's a rather bad idea to use `fs` as a variable name for `lru-cache` as you'll probably want to require the `fs` module at some point.

Comment: @m90: I correct the variable name. Here is the tree relevant struct:
`     .
   |-node_modules
   |---lru-cache
   |-----lib
   |-----test
`

Comment: Did you install the package using `npm install`?

Comment: @m90: No, I just move the directory. But this method works in other linux systems.

Comment: Then you are probably missing the module's own dependencies. *ALWAYS* install packages using npm. Just locate your root, do `npm init`, answer the questions, then do `npm install lru-cache --save` and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most node modules will have their own set of package dependencies so you cannot just copy the folder or clone the repository without making sure you are satisfying the module's dependencies.

The easiest way would be using `npm` for **ALL** package installations.

After you have run `npm init` in your project's root directory to set up your `package.json` use

```
$ npm install modulename --save
```

to install a package AND its dependencies. You can now safely use

```
var module = require('modulename');
```

throughout your whole project.

In case you cannot install your package via `npm` make sure all of its dependencies are installed as well by navigating to `node_modules/modulename` and running `npm install` (no arguments) here. This will install all dependencies that are listed in the modules own `package.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install
```

Sometimes npm has an issue and the dependency lru-cache may not get properly installed.